# How to visualize a branch point of order $n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

How do I interpret a branch point of order n? Here is a visualization of the imaginary part of the complex logarithm function. As the curve winds around the origin, the value of the imaginary part increases without bound.

[image]

In Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis, he says

> More generally, if $q$ is a branch point of some multifunction $f(z)$, and $f(z)$ first returns to its original value after $N$ revolutions round $q$, then $q$ is called an algebraic branch point of order $(N-1)$; an algebraic branch point of order 1 is called a simple branch point. We should stress that it is perfectly possible that $f(z)$ never returns to its original value, no matter how many times $z$ travels round $q$. In this case $q$ is called a logarithmic branch point -the name will be explained in the next section.

I am grasping how this works for a logarithmic branch point, but what might the surface look like for a branch point of order n? At some point the imaginary part will go up and up but it must return to its original value. What would this surface look like in comparison to the logarithmic case?

[image]

Here is a branch point of order $3$ but it doesn't show what the surface would look like only the behavior.

Comment: Real part of complex square root: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRD1s.jpg